# JavaFX Exporting table/treetable view content to pdf and excel

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, treetableview

I have a abstract table (table or treetable view does not matter) view which have lots of column. But not all columns are visible at the same time. Now what i want to do, when i export the table contents to pdf/excel read each row data but actually in javafx we can not get row and cell data directly. For this we must use row/cell factory. But in this case this factory is called only when we add data to the table. I can read table data model for each row but in this case i  must chek which columns are visible and invisible and which data model used always, and call the required method of the data model. Doing this required lots of code lines because as mentioned i have lots of column and nested column and also different data models. So during exporting to check all of these required lots of code line. But if i can read the row and cells of row i do't need to check invisible row and data model. Just read current row and data of cell. So my question is how can i solve this issued? Do you have any suggestion?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved this problem. Thanks for java documentation. I post some code snippet so who needs can use. For reading cell value on (row,column) intersection on **TreeTableView**

```
int rowIndex = treeTableView.getRow(treeRowItem);
for(int i=0;i<treeTable.getColumns();i++){
    TreeTableColumn ttc = treeTable.getColumns().get(i);
    String value = ttc.getCellData(rowIndex).toString();
}
```

you can also use the same logic on **TableView**